# class template for command pattern that supports undo

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, command-pattern, liskov-substitution-principle

> For simple commands that aren’t undoable and don’t require arguments,
>   we can use a class template to parameterize the command’s receiver.
>   We’ll define a template subclass SimpleCommand for such commands.
>   SimpleCommand is parameterized by the Receiver type and maintains a
>   binding between a receiver object and an action stored as a pointer to
>   a member function. [image]
>
> [image] Keep in mind that this
>   solution only works for simple commands. More complex commands that
>   keep track of not only their receivers but also arguments and/or undo
>   state require a Command subclass.

From : [GoF](http://www.worldcat.org/isbn/9780201633610)

Why commands that require to save undo state need command subclass?

Why cannot we do something like this?

```
class Memento
{   
};


class myMemento : public Memento
{
friend myclass;
};

class yourMemento : public Memento
{
friend yourclass;
};

class SupportsMemento
{
public:
    Memento * getMemento();
    reinstateMemento(Memento *);

};

class myclass : public SupportsMemento
{
    myMemento * getMemento();
    reinstateMemento(myMemento *); // breaks LSP
}

template<class Receiver>
class StandardCommand : public Command
{
public:
    typedef void (Receiver::*Action)();

    StandardCommand(Reciever * r, Action a):
        _receiver(r), _action(a){}
    virtual void execute();
    virtual void unexecute();
private:
    Receiver * _receiver;
    Action _action;
    Memento * m;
};

template<class Receiver>
void StandardCommand<Receiver>::execute()
{
    m=_reciever->getMemento();
    (_reciever->*_action)();
};

template<class Receiver>
void StandardCommand<Receiver>::unexecute()
{
    _receiver->reinstante_Memento(m);
};
```

Is it because it breaks [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), or is there any other reason behind this?

Comment: you make some assumptions about what we know.  I personally don't know how class Command looks like, what GoF and LSP are and what is the deal here with "complex" commands.

Comment: @bolov I have put clarification. And "complex" command has been explained in the context in which it has been used.

Comment: `(_reciever->*Action)();` <= this looks really fishy (and isn't valid as is). `Action` is a type. Did you mean `(this->*_action)();` (because `Action` is a method pointer for `Command`)?

Comment: @dhke yes, you are right, I have corrected it.

Comment: @q126y: That still should raise a compile time error. `Action` is a method pointer for a `Command` method. Did you mean `typedef void (Receiver::*Action)();`, instead?

Comment: @dhke ahh, yes. I should get some sleep.

Comment: As for the question: You assume that an action can be undone by rolling back to a specific state (the memento). Your receiver object has to cooperate to make this possible (by supporting state saving and rollback). This usually requires the saved state to be very generic, which might cause trouble for more complex commands (think e.g. "delete row from table", you don't want to save the whole table to delete a single row). If you don't have that problem, you can build a valid solution your way. GoF tends to mix language specific patterns with abstract concepts.